# IOS 11 StatusBar Changes

Tags: objective-c, ios10, ios11

We are upgrading our mobile application to ios 11, but there is a problem that I couldnt find any solution.

In IOS 10 we are making statusbar and navigationcontroller transparent , so the image below the navigationcontroller were starting from top of the screen.
However When I build the same code with xcode 9 and ios 11, result became like this:

[image: you can see the problem on top of the image]

The code that we were using in IOS 10 and xcode 8 is in below. Do you know what is changed in IOS 11 about navigation bar or status bar ?

```
if ([self.viewModel profileImage]) {
    if (diff <= 0) {
        self.statusBarBackground.alpha = 1.0;
    } else {
        self.statusBarBackground.alpha = 1.0;
        self.statusBarBackgroundHeight.constant = MIN(statusBarHeight, diff);
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of the view controller, are you using storyboard or is evertything in code?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be considered a fix, but I had the same issue, and I read somewhere that it is a bug in XCode 9 (I can't confirm that at this point), and after cleaning and rebuilding the app with XCode 8.3.3 the status bar was the correct color on the same iOS 11 device that had a white bar before, without making any changes to the code.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue you're having, but I fixed the issue by changing a constraint on my storyboard to top of container, not to the top layout guide. This caused a 20px gap on iOS 11 devices, but was fine on iOS 10 devices.

Answer (score 5):

> Try to set the contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior

```
 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```

or

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```

Comment: This method is for scrollViews only.

Comment: You can also do within Storyboard. Open Storyboard and select controller and select the attributes at top right side and untick the Under Top Bars option.

Comment: I had issue with web view, this helped